# Saving results to a file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I have a problem with this code.

What I am looking for in the code is to get the result of "first" and "second" randomly and put the result in a file.

It works great if I run it without using the file and I get all the correct results, but when I try to save the result in the file, I get only the first node which contains (first, secnd).

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

void main() 
{
    int first[100],secnd[100];

    for (int i=0; i<100 ;i++)
    {   
        first[i]=rand()%500;  //random number from  to 499
        secnd[i]=rand()%500;  //random number from  to 499
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("example.txt");
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        myfile <<first[i]<<" "<<secnd[i];
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The title has no useful information about the problem, the body says 'plzzzz help thanxxxx allot' and you're *seriously* expecting *anybody* to respond?

Comment: Please try to write in English, not text speak.

Comment: Ohh..  Either seek to end of file or open the file before the loop and keep it open until after.

Comment: Don't use `void main`, but `int main`, and always `return 0` at the end of your main function.

Comment: This didn't deserved to be closed. There was working code, accurate description of the expected output and the actual output. Granted there was some text speak which had to be interpreted, but I wish all posts to SO were this good.

Comment: I don't agree with the closing of this question. It is not too specific. It has general and wide implications for beginners. And ... this site should not be closed off to beginners.

Comment: Check the revisions. The original question that got closed was horrible.

Answer (score 5):

You are opening your file in the wrong place. You open the file *once* before the loop and close the file *once* after the loop. Like this.

```
myfile.open ("example.txt");
for (int i=0; i<100 ;i++)
{   
   ...
}
myfile.close();
```

When you open a file for output you delete what is currently in the file. So if you open the file inside the loop then you are losing the random numbers you had written before.

Comment: So he/she should open the file for appending for each subsequent attempt except the first, if he/she still persists in the inefficient act of re-opening and closing the file per iteration. Otherwise, the file would contain the results of the last iteration, wouldn't it? But he/she thinks the file contains only the first iteration results.

Comment: thanck you :) its work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You're reopening the file in the loop. This zeros the file each time, so you only get the last entry.

Answer (score 1):

The default open-flags for an `ofstream` are to truncate (overwrite) the file.  You are opening and closing the file every time through the loop.  If you want all results in the file, then open it ONCE outside the loop, and close it after the loop.